# Iterating two lists in a <rich:datatable> using <a4j:repeat>

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, richfaces, richdatatable

I have two `List<String>` and I'd like to put them in one `<rich:datatable>`, each `List<String>` should be a `column` on the `<rich:datatable>`. I'm trying to do that using `<a4j:repeat>`, but when I execute the program, only the headers of the `<rich:datatable>` appear, no content is shown on the `<rich:datatable>` .

Look at the code:

```
 <rich:dataTable>

              <rich:column> 
               <f:facet name="header">URI</f:facet>
                <a4j:repeat value="#{pesquisaBean.documentUriByTitleList}" var="uri">
                 #{uri}
                 </a4j:repeat>
              </rich:column>

              <rich:column>
               <f:facet name="header">Subject</f:facet>
               <a4j:repeat value="#{pesquisaBean.subjectByTitleList}" var="sub">
                 #{sub}
                 </a4j:repeat>
              </rich:column>

   </rich:dataTable>
```

What's the problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `datatable` can iterate through a list on its own, the `repeat` doesn't belong there. You should combine the lists into one (since I am assuming there is a relation between the URI and subject) and let the table iterate through that list. (i.e. you create an object that contains a URI and a subject and put it in a list)

```
<rich:dataTable value="#{bean.list}" var="item">
    <rich:column> 
        <f:facet name="header">URI</f:facet>
        #{item.uri}
    </rich:column>

    <rich:column> 
        <f:facet name="header">Subject</f:facet>
        #{item.sub}
    </rich:column>
</rich:dataTable>
```